# OpenVPN port sharing - can traffic be distinguished from HTTPS?

Tags: openvpn

I intend to set up OpenVPN with the port-share option on port 443.

> --port-share
>
> When run in TCP server mode, share the OpenVPN port with another application, such as an HTTPS server.

Can a network node which routers the OpenVPN traffic distinguis it from "regular" HTTPS traffic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page:

http://www.anonyproz.com/supportsuite/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=161&nav=0

suggests that a sufficiently motivated attacker can distinguish OpenVPN traffic from HTTPS.